# Get List common value count

Tags: java, list, compare

I have two `ArrayList<Long>` with huge size about 5,00,000 in each. I have tried using for loop which usage `list.contains(object)`, but it takes too much time. I have tried by splitting one list and comparing in multiple threads but no effective result found.

I need the no. of elements that are same in both list.

Any optimized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered putting you elements into a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead? This would make the lookups much faster. This would of course only work if you don't have duplicates.

If you have duplicates you could construct [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that has the value as the key and the count as the value.

Answer (score 3):

Let `l1` be the first list and `l2` the second list. In Big O notation, that runs in `O(l1*l2)`

Another approach could be to insert one list into a `HashSet`, then for all other elements in the other list test if it exist in the HashSet. This would give roughly `2*l1+l2 -> O(l1+l2)`

Comment: A `HashSet` only contains **one** value, in your case the `Long` you're storing.

Comment: Sorry, saw `HashSet` and read `HashMap`. And since he is looking for dups, the removal of dups in a single list is not a issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it be closer to `l1 + (l2 * log (l1))` as the lookup for each element of `l2` in `l1` would take `O(log(l1))`

Comment: @JohnB, no the lookup executes in constant time `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

General mechanism would be to sort both lists and then iterate the sorted lists looking for matches.

Answer (score 1):

A list isn't a efficient data structure when you have much elements, you have to use a data structure more efficent when you search a element. 
For example an tree or a hashmap!

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that list one has m elements and list two has n elements , m>n. If elements are not numerically ordered , it seems that they are not , total number of comparison steps - that is the cost of the method - factor mxn - n^2/2. In this case cost factor is about 50000x49999.

Keeping both lists ordered will be the optimal solution. If lists are ordered , cost of comparison of these will be factor m. In this case that is about 50000. This optimal result will be achieved , when both of lists are iterated via two cursor. This method can be represented in code as follows :

```
int i=0,j=0;
int count=0;
while(i<List1.size() && j<List2.size())
{
    if(List1[i]==List2[j])
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    else if(List1[i]<List2[j])
        i++;
    else
        j++;
}
```

If it is possible for you to keep lists ordered all the time , this method will make difference. Also I consider that it is not possible split and compare unless lists are ordered.